# How do you convert date to moment

Tags: mongodb, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a date (moment) that I store in a db (mongo) and then compare to the current date to get the difference. However, I can't use `diff()` when I retrieve the past date from db and use the current moment. In the db insert, I'm inserting `{startDate:moment(), ...}`. Then, after I retrive the `startDate` date, I try to get diff

```
var now = moment();
console.log(now.diff(startDate))
```

But it throws an [error](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

I store the `moment` rather then the js `date` object but I am still getting the error, so I'm not sure how how I'm actually supposed to get the diff of a stored value and compare it to current moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert `startDate:moment()`, that will save the contents of the `moment` object .. not a `Date` field as you might be expecting.

For example, in the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.mycollection.insert({startDate:moment()})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.mycollection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5401a7805a5b0e4e0bfe5170"),
    "startDate" : {
        "_isAMomentObject" : true,
        "_i" : null,
        "_f" : null,
        "_l" : null,
        "_strict" : null,
        "_isUTC" : false,
        "_pf" : {
            "empty" : false,
            "unusedTokens" : [ ],
            "unusedInput" : [ ],
            "overflow" : -2,
            "charsLeftOver" : 0,
            "nullInput" : false,
            "invalidMonth" : null,
            "invalidFormat" : false,
            "userInvalidated" : false,
            "iso" : false
        },
        "_d" : ISODate("2014-08-30T10:29:20.529Z")
    }
}
```

There is a proper `Date` saved within the `startDate._d` field, but I think what you actually want to do is save a single value in the `startDate` field using the `new Date()` constructor:

```
>  db.mycollection.insert({startDate:new Date()})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> doc = db.mycollection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5401a8fe5a5b0e4e0bfe5173"),
    "startDate" : ISODate("2014-08-30T10:35:42.736Z")
}
```

Now you should be able to perform date math as expected:

```
> var now = moment();

// Diff in milliseconds (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)
> now.diff(doc.startDate)
6825
```

Comment: You should use moment's `.toDate()` function rather than trying to construct a date from a moment.  Or just leave moment out of the insert and call `new Date()` without parameters.

Comment: You're correct that you shouldn't use the `_d` property.  It's not part of moment's public API.

Comment: to clear things up, I also tried using var date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); then stored it into db, but it didn't work when I did diff with now = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); . However, storing newDate(moment()) and moment().toDate() did work. Thanks

Comment: @MattJohnson: Agreed, a simple `new Date()` is fine. I was thinking there might be other options with the moment() call (eg. if using timezones or other relative date conveniences) but that wasn't a great example :).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Date object to moment.js constructor directly.

```
var my_date = new Date()
moment(my_date)
```